# UFO Legality piece from 1970s-1980s analog

Tags: story-identification, laws, ufo

I am looking for a story that highlights what would happen to UFOS/Aliens if they landed on the planet from a legality standpoint, including the UN and immigration status. I remember reading it from one of my dad's sci-fi digests from the late 70's to early 80s, and I would like to say Analog but I am unsure. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know if it's your story, but I remember a lot about a similar one. Alien turns out to be young and female. Her parents were exiled for "having their own minds" (telepathic) Defence lawyer quotes poem on Statue of Liberty "give me your tired, your poor". At the end the alien goes to live with a blind veteran, to "be his eyes". I can't remember the title or author though.

Comment: Real life example! Norman Thagard, the first US astronaut to live on the Mir space station, was launched aboard a Soyuz craft but returned to Earth - along with his two Russian fellow cosmonauts - on the Space Shuttle. Late in the day it was realised that by the letter of the law the Russians would need immigration visas to enter the United States so this was fast-tracked to enable them to disembark after landing!

Answer (score 3):

[*A Bad Day for Vermin*](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/51258/pg51258-images.html) by Keith Laumer (which was published in *Galaxy* magazine in 1964) is a (somewhat) humorous look at the legal ramifications of extraterrestrial beings landing on the Earth.

A UFO lands near the courthouse in a small town.  A being comes out of the UFO and uses a translator device to speak to the townspeople (and the local judge.)  At that point, a local hick walks up and shoots the alien dead - he claims there's no law against it because the alien isn't a human and murder laws only apply to humans.  He also tries to get out of other charges (unlawful use of a weapon in town and others) by proving that he is licensed to own and use the pistol and that he's a licensed exterminator - he's just "exterminated" a "varmint" for the city for free.

In response, the judge organizes a town meeting in which the townspeople pass two new laws.  One defines "human" as applied to murder laws.  The other defines "varmints" and appoints a legal "exterminator."

A "human" is a harmless creature.  A creature that commits violent acts is a "varmint," and subject to summary "extermination" from the newly appointed exterminator.

The hick who killed the alien is exterminated on the spot with his own pistol.

Answer (score 0):

[*Buy Jupiter!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buy_Jupiter) by Isaac Asimov is a story where Aliens wish to buy Jupiter as Advertising Space but they are legally required to purchase it from Earth.  Not that anyone on Earth is aware of this, especially as this is the first confirmation of extra terrestrial life, so the Aliens are obliging themselves to an Alien legal system rather than just hanging the letters on it.

The Terrestrial Foundation realizes they have more valuable space in the solar system they can sell, namely the planet Saturn.

Answer (score -3):

*[Stranger in a Strange Land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stranger_in_a_Strange_Land)* by Robert Heinlein fits, where the only human survivor on the first mission to Mars is legally entitled to the planet but he doesn't know this.  In fact, this was what the Mars mission was originally, after the first moon landing created a huge debacle in land claims.

He becomes chased by the self-interested, and especially the military and government, with the express purpose of cheating him out his claims.
The story evolves beyond that where the first man from Mars, a reverse Jungle Book (Heinlein said he was inspired by Tarzan), changes the world order in many ways and becomes a target for it.

The initial interest in him for this is largely forgotten in the second half of the book.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  While tangentially interesting, this doesn't really answer the question.  (As you seem to acknowledge.)  Please don't post commentary as an answer; when you earn some reputation you'll be able to leave comments on posts.  You might want to take the [tour].